# Laravel - Customize model event

Tags: laravel

So my Comment model has the following model events:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    self::created(function ($model) {
        /** @var self $model */
        $model->clearCache();
    });

    self::updated(function ($model) {
        /** @var self $model */
        $model->clearCache();
    });

    self::deleted(function ($model) {
        /** @var self $model */
        $model->clearCache();
    });
```

However, is there any way I can customize this a bit? So let's say I wanted the Updated Model Event to trigger any time it's updated, but if it's updated a certain way (like having a specific column updated), it could pass a special parameter.

Something like this:

```
    self::updated(function ($model) {
       if (//// "text" column update)
        $model->clearCache(1);
       } else {
        $model->clearCache(0);
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.html#method_getDirty

`getDirty()` : Get the attributes that have been changed since the last sync.

```
self::updated(function ($model) {
   $columns = $model->getDirty();

   foreach ($columns as $column => $newValue) {
     echo $column; // One of the changed columns.
     if ($column == 'YOUR_COLUMN_NAME')
        $model->clearCache(1);
     } else {
        $model->clearCache(0);
   }
}
});
```

Comment: I don't really like this solution as this adds a database query on every model update.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I came up with is to just update the model quietly, then call the function I want while passing the parameter I want:

```
$comment->saveQuietly();
        
$comment->clearCache($parameter);
```